# Query sort in coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-10

I have a group of data from excel file read the file and take the result in a variable for create a new excel with what are wrong and i try

```
local.sheetData =queryNew("FirstName,LastName,Address,Email,Phone,DOB,Role");
        for(row in data){
            queryAddRow(local.sheetData);
         
            if(row["First Name"] != '' || row["Last Name"] != '' || row["Address"] != '' || row["Email"] != '' || row["Phone"] != '' || row["DOB"] != '' || row["Role"] != ''){
                if(row["First Name"] === '' || row["Last Name"] === '' || row["Address"] === '' || row["Email"] === '' || row["Phone"] === '' || row["DOB"] === '' || row["Role"] === ''){

                    local.endresult = arrayToList(local.nullMessage)
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "FirstName", row["First Name"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "LastName", row["Last Name"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Address", row["Address"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Email", row["Email"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Phone", row["Phone"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "DOB", row["DOB"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Role", row["Role"]);
                   
                }else{
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "FirstName", row["First Name"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "LastName", row["Last Name"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Address", row["Address"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Email", row["Email"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Phone", row["Phone"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "DOB", row["DOB"]);
                    querySetCell(local.sheetData, "Role", row["Role"]);
                    
                }
            } 
        }
        
       return local.sheetData;
```

it working fine and get the result like

[image]

i wand sort this query and show the any cell is empty that row show first. how to sort the query in coldfusion ?

Comment: Could it be that `data` already is a query object in your case? How does `WriteDump(data)` look like?

Comment: @Tomalak the image is result

Comment: That's what `local.sheetData` looks like. I asked what `data` looks like.

Comment: Oh sorry ,its show query resultset

Comment: Then you can throw away your entire `queryNew`/`queryAddRow` loop and use Query-of-Queries to build `local.sheetData` from the start.

Comment: ya now i use Query-of-Queries  by adding a increment value in if condition and write query sort by id ,so it working well ,i will try this way thank you for your support

Comment: Just as a heads up so you dont run into this later the `===` (`row["First Name"] === ''`) in your code does not work like javascript so you will probably just want to use a `==`

Comment: It looks like the issue you are trying to solve is importing an excel sheet and its importing blank rows that have no data, check out https://github.com/cfsimplicity/spreadsheet-cfml can probably accomplish your task easier than your current solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to sort a query in ColdFusion is to use the Query-of-Queries feature.

tag syntax

```
<cfset myQuery = ...>
<cfquery name="sortedQuery" dbtype="query">
  SELECT * FROM myQuery ORDER BY col1, col2 DESC;
</cfquery>
```

cfscript syntax

```
var myQuery = ...;
var sortedQuery = queryExecute("
   SELECT * FROM myQuery ORDER BY col1, col2 DESC;
", {}, {dbtype: "query"});
```

In any case - if you insert rows in the right order, you don't need to sort anything, so pre-sorting `data` before your loop would be the most efficient option you have.

Comment: my datas are coming from an excel file

Comment: @Shambu That does not matter. Once you have read the data into a Coldfusion query variable, you can use that variable in Query of Query logic (to create a sorted query like the answer).